# How to continue numbered/bulletted lists after a construct that requires starting leftmost margin

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I am uncertain how to handle the following mixed code/list constructs:

*Note: pretend the 2 backticks below were actually 3 for a proper fenced code block ..)*

```
``java

                    startHttpServer();
                    System.out.println(
                            "Http Server Listening on " + SConstants.HTTP_PORT + SConstants.HTTP_PROJECT_NAME);


``

        @ Logging level can be calibrated by simple change(s) to logging.xml and/or log4j.properties
            - _Comments_: this seems to be mostly in place
        @ Errors and exceptions go to appropriate WARN and/or ERROR logging levels
```

Here is the result: notice all of the content after the code fence starting with   are distorted by incorrect font, indentation, and loss of numbering:

[image]

This same issue shows for any Constructs that require left-most margin:

- code fences
- images and links

How should this document section be restructured to retain ability to include the code fences, url's and images yet without disturbing the numbering, font, and indentation?

btw I'm running the `markdown` through `pandoc` : not sure if the latter were involved in causing the issue or if this were native `markdown` issue.

**Update** Here is final version that does work: with an assist from the accepted answer of @eskwaryd

```
1. Code Behaviors
    1. Logging
        @.  No "bare" `System.out.println` 's

            _Comments_:  _Many_ of these exist. Here is a partial list

            Here is one code example

            ``java

                                startHttpServer();
                                System.out.println(
                                        "Http Server Listening on " + SparcleConstants.HTTP_PORT + SparcleConstants.HTTP_PROJECT_NAME);
            ``

        @.  Logging level can be calibrated by simple change(s) to logging.xml and/or log4j.properties
            - _Comments_: this seems to be mostly in place
        @.  Errors and exceptions go to appropriate WARN and/or ERROR logging levels

            - _Comments_: Exceptions and errors may be swallowed: this is an exposure
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indent your code block to match the indent of your list item. For example:

````
1.  Section one

    1.  Item One

        ```java
        code goes here...
        ```

    2.  Item two

    3.  Item three

2.  Section two
````

Results in:

1. Section one

   1. Item One

      ```java
      code goes here...
      ```
   2. Item two
   3. Item three
2. Section two

Comment: Hmm I can try that (again - i did several times before) with code blocks - though I would have preferred the code blocks to be all the way to the left I guess that is not supported.  On another note: how to do this with links / images?  If they are indented it flat out is not working.

Comment: Tried the indent for the code block again - still does not work. I'll show in OP

Comment: I did some more doctoring and it works now: see the OP. I'll give you the "win" because after the re-work it does function also with the indentation.